# How to show and save DATE_RFC2822 to MySQL using Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, laravel-5.3

I want to save `Fri, 20 Jan 2017 09:27:22 +0200` to MySQL database. 
In my database table I have `TIMESTAMP` 
What function I should use for inserting this string to MySQL?
I tried using `date(`Fri, 20 Jan 2017 09:27:22 +0200`)` but when I pass value back to view I get `2017-01-20` in my array.
So 1st how to save it correctly?
2nd how to get it back from MySQL back the same as passed?

Comment: Only Tip that i can give: If you want to use an dateformat that is not supported by mysql, better not use a `TIMESTAMP` field, use `VARCHAR` and save the date as string.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format  & http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to handle your issue:

1. Make and real timestamp from your given date with `strtotime()`:

   `print $timestamp = strtotime('Fri, 20 Jan 2017 09:27:22 +0200');`
2. Save the timestamp `1484897242` into the database.
3. Get the timestamp from the database and reformat it:

   `print date(DATE_RFC2822,$timestamp);//Fri, 20 Jan 2017 09:27:22 +0200`

This is what you basically have to do. Have a try.

Answer (score -1):

Try Carbon,it's laravel core lib, very easy to handle laravel date manipulation. The document link is [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: Link-only answers and library recommendations are both off topic here.